# i have a jsp page where we select the object and by submitting the form the route travelled by it

Tags: jsp

i have a jsp page where we select the object and by submitting the form the route travelled by it will be displayed on the google map by fetching the lat long from db. Now, i need to refresh the map using ajax.Pls help me how to do this

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, share some lines of your code please.

Comment: I'm sure google has instructions how to get their data, look that up. Then learn how to use ajax (GWT would be a logical choice, Google no doubt integrates well with Google) and apply that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #map_canvas {
    width:550px;
    height:400px;
}
</style>

<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
       function initialize(){
       var center= new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552,76.327043);
       var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: center,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                navigationControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       }     
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      var polylineCoordinates = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566,76.331549), 
      new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566,76.331463),
      new google.maps.LatLng(10.013503,76.331313),
      new google.maps.LatLng(10.013482,76.331205),
      :
      :
      :
      ];// here instead of this apply your logic to retrieve latitude and longitude values from your database

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(10.012404,76.32622),
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 3.5,
                strokeColor: '#FF3300'   
            },
            draggable: true,
            map: map
            });          
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: polylineCoordinates,
          strokeColor: '#5C5CE6',
          strokeOpacity: 2.0,
          strokeWeight: 5,
          editable: false
      });

      polyline.setMap(map);    
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.load_tweets').load('index1.jsp');
  },30000);
});

        </script>

        <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load').load('index1.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize();">
        <div id="map_canvas" ></div><br>
        <div id="load"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```